# Python Basics: How to convert a list containing an int into a plain int?

Tags: python

Why is this not giving me just "3" but still "[3]"?

```
a = [3]
print "".join(str(a))
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check `print str(a)` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps just dereference by index:

```
print a[0]
```

Or:

```
for item in a:
    print item
```

Answer (score 8):

because you call the to string function on the entire list

try:

```
a = [3]
print "".join([str(v) for v in a])
```

After reading the headline of the question are you just trying to get a single integer from a list, or do you want to convert a list of integer into a "larger" integer, e.g.:

```
a = [3, 2]
print "".join([str(v) for v in a]) ## This gives a string and not integer
>>> "32"
```

Comment: thanks! this works but its quite a lot of code...isn't that a bit unpythonic?

Comment: if your list only contains one integer and you want that integer, yes, just access the index a[0] will give the integer value 3, but if your list contains multiple integer, you want to concatinate, you must specify how to do that

Comment: You could simplify very slightly by removing the square brackets, but  using string join syntax with a list comprehension would be considered very pythonic :D

Answer (score 4):

You are taking str() on an array.  str convers [3] to "[3]".  You are probably looking for

```
"".join(str(i) for i in a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `str(a)` gives you the string representation of a list, ie, "[3]".

Try

```
"".join([str(elem) for elem in a])
```

to convert the list of ints to a list of strings before joining.

Answer (score 1):

This would produce the expected behavior:

```
"".join([str(x) for x in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a generator expression to join rather then a list comprehension:

```
"".join(str(x) for x in a)
```

If your list only contains numbers you might use repr() instead since thats what str() is going to do anyway:

```
"".join(repr(x) for x in a)
```

If your using python 2.X you can use backticks as a shortcut for repr(). But this isn't available in 3.X:

```
"".join(`x` for x in a)
```